# Dirichlet problem with separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle

Use separation of variables to find a nonzero solution for the following Dirichlet problem:

$\Delta u = 0$ in $\Omega$ with $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$, where $\Omega = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: 0 < y < \pi\}$

$\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is open and bounded, u is harmonic on $\Omega$.

If we assume that $u \in C^{2}(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega})$, then according to the maximum principle for harmonic functions we have:

$0 = \min_{y \in \partial \Omega} u(y) \leq u(x) \leq \max_{y \in \partial \Omega} u(y) = 0$ $\hspace{3mm} \forall x \in \Omega \hspace{3mm}$ (since $u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$)

Hence u(x) = 0 for all $x \in \Omega$.

I have the feeling that there does not exist a nonzero solution, because of this maximum principle. So how do I know that there does exist a nonzero solution and how can I find this solution. I think I need to assume that there exist a solution $u(x,y) = X(x) \cdot Y(y)$. Then $0 = \Delta u = u_{xx} + u_{yy} = Y(y) \cdot X''(x) + X(x) \cdot Y''(y)$. So $X''(x) + aX(x) = 0$ and $Y''(y) + b \cdot Y(y) = 0$ for some constants $a = a(y)$ and $b = b(x)$. And then solve these ODEs for $X(x)$ and $Y(y)$. So $u(x,y) = X(x) \cdot Y(y) = (c_{1} \cdot \cos(\sqrt{a}x) + c_{2} \cdot \sin(\sqrt{a} x)) \cdot (d_{1} \cdot \cos(\sqrt{b}y) + d_{2} \cdot \sin(\sqrt{b} y))$

And we know that $u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$. So that means that $u(x,0) = 0$ and $u(x,\pi) = 0$.
And with these boundary values, I only find that $d_{1} = 0$.

So how to continue then?
And what does this Dirichlet problem tell is then about the maximum principle and what is wrong about my conclusion that $u(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \Omega$?

Comment: Indeed $u = e^x \sin y$ solves the Dirichlet problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain $\Omega$ is unbounded, in particular you do not know whether the solution u attains a maximum, which is an essential condition for the maximum principle to be applicable.

As you already observed, with the separation of variables Ansatz $u(x,y) = X(x)\cdot Y(y)$, the following formulas are obtained:
$$
 X(x) = c_1  \cos(\sqrt{a}x) + c_2 \sin( \sqrt{a}x), \quad Y(y)=  d_2 \sin(\sqrt{b}y),
$$
where we used $d_1 = 0$ (due to boundary condition). Now observe that
$
 a := \frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)} = -b,
$
assuming $b> 0$, we see that
$$
 X(x) = c_1 \cos(i\sqrt{b}x) + c_2 \sin(i\sqrt{b}x).
$$
At this point, we have found a complex solution, in order to find a real solution, set $z = \sqrt{b}x$ and use the identity
$
 \cos(iz) -i \sin(iz)  = e^z
$
(i.e. we have to choose $c_1 = 1, c_2 = -i$). Thus we arrive at
$
X(x) = e^{\sqrt{b}x},
$
and consequently
$$
 u(x,y) = e^{\sqrt{b}x} \cdot d_2 \sin(\sqrt{b}y).
$$
Since $u_{xx} = bu, u_{yy} = -bu$, we see that u is a solution.

Comment: Okay, so then since $\Omega$ is unbounded, we cannot apply the maximum principles. And then I did find an expression for $u(x,y)$ with $d_{1} = 0$. But what about the term $X(x)$? How do I convert that to an exponential power, since I have no complex numbers here.

Comment: Setting $c_{1}=1$ and $c_{2} = -i$ is just trial and error then? You assume those values and then you observe that for those values we arrive at a solution.

Comment: $\cos(iz)-i\sin(iz) = e^z$ is a general identity and holds for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. We arrived at $X(x) = c_1 \cos(iz) + c_2 \sin(iz)$, where we are free to choose $c_1, c_2$. So in order to apply the general identity, we have to choose $c_1 =1, c_2 = -i$.

Comment: Yes, I know this identity. But I was just wondering why you are free to choose those constants. And I think it's just a matter of trial and error. You just try if you have a solution for those values. But thanks then.

Comment: When you want to solve the ODE $X''(x) +aX(x) = 0$ without boundary conditions, you see that there are infinitely many possible solutions. More precisley, from ODE theory one knows that the solution space is two-dimensional: any solution X can be parametrized by two variables, in your notation $c_1,c_2$. This is why no matter how we choose $c_1$ and $c_2$, the function $X$ will always be a solution to the ODE. You could also choose $c_1 = 1, c_2 =1$, but then the solution you obtain is complex, and not real: $X(x) = \cos(i\sqrt{b}x) +  \sin(i\sqrt{b}x)$.

Comment: Ahaa, okay thanks!